# What do you call “I'll not feed you by my own hand” in English

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I don’t know how to describe this properly. I just translated what description to English that I use in my native language (*Bangla*/বাংলা)

The situation is like this: Some people always need others’ help to do things. They seek help for every little step. If you aggregate the help, you'll find that they didn't do anything by themselves. They got someone to help them to do every small task.

For example, Robert asks Andrew how to post question on https://english.stackexchange.com/. Then he asks where to type the title even though the *Title* input label is seen very clearly. After that Robert will ask “*Hey Andrew, Could you tell me some good title sentences that I can put here?*” It goes on.

Robert is not actually asking questions. He is asking for so many details that it makes Andrew do the whole task.

My question is how to tell Andrew, “I can not feed you every time by my own hand”?

Is there any single word? Any idiom?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the idiom you are looking for is:

> I can't keep spoon-feeding you forever.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you are looking for is *[hand-holding](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hand-holding)*:

> : solicitous attention, support, or instruction

This is more general.  If you are indeed looking specifically for something about food, Jim is spot-on.  You could also consider [this Chinese proverb](http://www.bartleby.com/73/484.html):

> Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and
>   you feed him for a lifetime.

Comment: *Spoon-feeding* applies more generally than just in the context of food.   I might as well say that if OP is talking about assisting a small child in their first attempts to walk then you are spot-on. I think really though that *hand-holding* applies when you are performing some actions for someone while *spoon-feeding* applies when providing answers or information

Comment: @Jim Thats a great. why not you put it in answer?